# Get matching records in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm not sure if this is obvious and I don't see it because it is late here, but right now I'm struggling with the following:

[image]

I'm trying to find out if there is a match somewhere. So, profile 2 liked profile 1 and also, profile 1 liked profile 2. That would be a match.

I tried combining arrays but that that ran nowhere. ._. How could I archive this in Laravel queries?

Answer (score 3):

```
$likey = DB::table('likes AS liker')
        ->join('likes AS liked', 'liker.liked_id', '=', 'liked.liker_id')
        ->select('liked.liker_id', 'liked.liked_id')
        ->where('liker.liker_id', '=', 'liked.liked_id')
        ->get();
```

Something along those lines.

EDIT: Just to clarify this solution so you don't get into temptation of copy pasting this and never figuring out what just happened here;

we are joining (using INNER JOIN, very important) this table to itself simpy because (just like you've said it) we have to check it twice. First for the liker (the one who liked someones profile first), than for the liked (the one who responded with a like in return) user. Having that in mind, we join this table checking liked_id from the first table on liker_id on the second table.

Which should give us joined result looking like:

```
liker.liker_id | liker.liked_id | liked.liker_id | liked.liked_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2              | 1              | 1              | 2
1              | 2              | 2              | 1
```

Mind you this will give us duplicates! (VERY IMPORTANT).

Having that in mind I would think about redisigning your table. For example adding boolean column named "liked_back" will give you much cheaper and cleaner queries rather than doing whatever this is...

Comment: The query did not work, but thats fine. Adding another column might be the better option so I'll give this a try. Thanks.